# Hide the correct menu nav bar - react

Tags: reactjs, nav

I am trying to write a react component to render a menu, but I need to use just **CSS** for controlling the visibility, but I have a problem that I cannot able to solve.

I have set a hover on the element with the class menu, then it set the child called wrapSubMenu to **visible** but it is setting all menu's children. I pretend to Do it just on the first wrapSubMenu of the menu.
[image]

[Playground here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kjmczj?file=menu/menu.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

They have the same class style, you cannot complete that on this way.

Try to do it with state toggling on hover, instead of css

Comment: I have thought to do this, but I think that I will be more complex and will spend a lot of time using State.

Comment: it's more complex to do correctly it in css